# Showing coercivity of a function

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-optimization

I am well attuned to the definition for a function to be coerce,
which is that $\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$
ie the values of $f$ go to infinity as the norm goes to infinity.

So

Ex.1 $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1^4 + x_2^4 - 3x_1x_2$

I thought this was immediately obvious because 
$x_1^4$ and $x_2^4$ grow faster than the linear terms we have.
 Would this be considered a sufficient proof?

I am unsure in particular how taking the limit would be shown.

Additionally, I don't see why functions like

Ex.2 $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = a^tx$ isn't coercive,

or

Ex.3 $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 2x_1x_2$ isn't coercive.

Since they are both unbounded, doesn't taking the norm of $x \to \infty$ show that these functions also approach infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ex.1 No, your answer is not rigorous. It *is* true, but you need to prove it. My suggestion is to show that $$\lim_{\|(x_1,x_2)\| \to +\infty} \frac{x_1 x_2}{x_1^4+x_2^4}=0.$$

Ex.2 If $x \perp a$, then $f(x)=0$. And since on the subspace $\{a\}^\perp$ there are vectors of arbitrarily large norm...

Ex. 3 If $x_1=x_2=t$, then $f(t,t)=0$ for any $t>0$. Letting $t \to +\infty$...

Comment: for Ex.1 Is this a general approach you would use to show  the function is coercive? Ultimately you're just showing it converges, but say if I had something a little bit eccentric;

$e^{x_1^2+x_2^2} + (x_1^2+x_2^2+3x_2)^{500}$, 
I suspect I cannot use limits to show that it is not coercive.

Comment: There is no standard way to prove coercivity. You must look at the particular form of your function, and try hard.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x_1, x_2) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 2x_1x_2$$ is not coercive because 
$f(x_1,x_2) = (x_1 - x_2)^2$, meaning that $f(x,x) = 0$ no matter how large $x$ is.

This means that the statement

> For all $M>0$, there exists a $N>0$ such that for all $x, ||x||> N$, it is true that $f(x) > M$

Is not true for this function.

Similarly, for $f(x) = a^T x$, you know that if $v$ is perpendicular to $a$, then $f(\alpha v) = 0$ for every value of $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: ah, right. I never thought of viewing it in the way where you've factorised it like that. This is interesting to think about.

However, for the linear case of $a^Tx$ why can do we assume we can only take values of $v$ which are perpendicular to $a$, if you know what I mean? If we selected a non-perpendicular $v$, then $$f(a,v) \neq 0 \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: @diabloescobar That is true, but that does not change the fact that $f(a,v) = 0$ if $v$ is perpendicular to $a$, no matter how large $v$ is.

Comment: alright, thank-you!